# PHP MySQL pool show highest voted and votes

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, forms

I am running a PHP script to save a pool into database
My MySQL looks like this

```
ID    QUESTION_1
1     1 or 2 or 3 ( according to the chosen option value in number )
```

If I vote in QUESTION_1 I can vote option 1 or 2 or 3 and the number of the chosen value is saved in MySQL as number 1 or 2 or 3

WHAT I NEED

If most people voted option 2 let's say 348 times, and in second place people chosed option 3 with 208 votes and in third place comes option 3 with 87 votes I need to show:

```
Option 2 winner with 348 votes
Option 3 with 208 votes
option 2 with 87 votes
```

We show the winner and how many votes ...

I am trying to do this like this

```
$r['total']=0;
foreach(array(1,2,3) as $QUESTION_1){
  $res=mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT COUNT(QUESTION_1) AS `total` 
                                  FROM `votes` WHERE `QUESTION_1` = '$QUESTION_1' ");
  $tmp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
  $r=max($tmp['total'],$r['total']);
 }


 echo number_format($r,0,',','.');
```

But I am new to PHP so any help is welcome

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment.  What class are you taking?   In plain english (not code) how do you think you should proceed.  Lay it out in steps.  There are places where your question doesn't make sense?  look at the `echo` code snippet.  What happened to option #1?  Why is option #2 listed twice?

Comment: Show your table structure and what you want to reach.

Comment: I edited the question, now it is easy to understand it

Comment: what you can do, is add one to question 1 column when ever some body vote, than you can run select query, and order them by vote ASC, how you are trying to do here, is making a simple job complicated, if you dont understand what i am trying to say let me know, i will post it as solution, but when you tell me to post the solution, also try to tell what you dont understand, and mysqli does not automatically secure your code, what the vedio, which  i created to know why your code is vunrable, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgogIRji28U

Comment: ARIF_SUHAIL The truth is that I do not understand, I am new to PHP. Can you write a solution so I can also select it as the correct answer please

Comment: The problem is that right now the vote has been started so the values are already saved as 1 or 2 or 3 depending on the chosen option in the pool

Comment: @caradevineros  posted the answer let me know you understand or not, or the solution is right or not.

Comment: use this query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2971d9/4) as boilerplate. then fetch records by php and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You dont need much code to that, answer is long as i try to explain every thing but the code is short**

This is very important that you read the comment, first have a look at at my database picture[image]

as you can see in here people choose option 2, three times

they choose option 1, two times

and than they choose options 3 only one times,

so option 2 is winner with 3 votes, option 1 is at second place with 2 votes and option 3 is at third place with one vote

**so your display should look like this**

option    1    winner with    3    votes

option    2    with    2    votes

option    3    with    1    votes

If i am right till now, read further, other wise attach a picture of your database, with your question, and let me know,

**Solution - You dont need much code to do this, just use the code down below**

```
$res = mysqli_query($datacenter,"SELECT   *, COUNT(QUESTION_1) as total FROM 
    `votes` GROUP BY QUESTION_1 ORDER BY total DESC");
    $declration = ['winner with','with','with'];
    $i=0; // you dont need this line, but if you dont need this it will show you 
// the index error but your code will work fine
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
           echo 'option '.' &nbsp;&nbsp; '. $row['QUESTION_1'].' &nbsp;&nbsp; '.
     $declration[$i++].' &nbsp;&nbsp; '. $row['total']. ' &nbsp;&nbsp; '. 
    'votes<br>';

    }
```

**Explanation - first query explanation**

```
SELECT   *, COUNT(QUESTION_1) as total FROM `votes` GROUP BY QUESTION_1 ORDER BY total DESC
```

what query is simply saying select every thing and than count number question_1 which are repeating it self,   and order them by number of repeated value, and in the end i am saying order them by total  DESC, if i dont order them, its fine, but than i have to sort the result, so that's why i am ordering them now.

**if you run this query in your localhost you will get the result like this** 
[image]

as you can our result is nicely sorted, so only think now we have to work on our display message.

**I am using the array to display the result**

do display the result, instead of typing them plainly  i am using the the array, declration

```
$declration = ['winner with','with','with'];
```

the reason i am using array, as it make my job easier, as you can see first value is `winner with`, than second its `with` and third is `with` as well, try to change the second and third value, some thing like runner up or third place, and your display will change as well.

**now the fetching and display**

```
echo 'option '.' &nbsp;&nbsp; '. $row['QUESTION_1'].' &nbsp;&nbsp; '. $declration[$i++].' &nbsp;&nbsp; '. $row['total']. ' &nbsp;&nbsp; '. 'votes<br>';
```

i am using `&nbsp;` just to create another space, rest of you will be understand, if you dont understand, what this part is doing `$declration[$i++],` change the value in our original `$declration` array, you will be able to understand,

and this message is really important, your code is vunrable to sql injection, please do a reasearch or watch the vedio,

any confusion let me know

Comment: Very elaborated and perfect answer